# Cannot have navigator inside of tabs in onsen-react

Tags: reactjs, onsen-ui

I am trying to have a `Navigator` inside of a `Tab` which results in an error. A complete code snippet that reproduces the error is given below. In the snippet we have two tabs. The navigator sits inside the first tab. We do not even need to add multiple pages to the navigator - the problem occurs even in this simple setup where the navigator only shows the `initialRoute`, that is, the first page.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/LucNaterop/pen/QqbBwp?&editors=101)

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

import ons from 'onsenui';
import * as Ons from 'react-onsenui';
import 'onsenui/css/onsenui.css';
import 'onsenui/css/onsen-css-components.css';

class FirstTab extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Ons.Page>
                <h1>First Tab</h1>
            </Ons.Page>
        );
    }
}

class Navigator extends React.Component {
    renderPage(route, navigator) {
        return <FirstTab key={0}/>
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Ons.Navigator
                initialRoute={{ 'name': 'firstTab' }}
                renderPage={this.renderPage.bind(this)}
            />
        );
    }
}

class SecondPage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Ons.Page>
                <h1>Second Tab</h1>
            </Ons.Page>
        );
    }
}

class Tabs extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {index: 0};
    }
    renderTabs() {
        return [
            { tab: <Ons.Tab label='First Tab' key={0} />, content: <Navigator key={0}/>},
            { tab: <Ons.Tab label='Second Tab' key={1} />,content: <SecondPage key={1} />}
        ];
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Ons.Tabbar
                position='auto'
                index={this.state.index}
                onPreChange={(event) => {
                    if (event.index != this.state.index) {
                        this.setState({index: event.index});
                    }
                }}
                renderTabs={this.renderTabs.bind(this)}
            />
        );
    }
}

// on startup
render(<Tabs />, document.getElementById('render-target'));
```

The problem here is that once we select the tab which contains the navigator (in this case the default tab) we cannot switch tabs anymore. Any click on a tab results in the error

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid state: page element must be a "ons-page" element.
```

which leaves the user trapped inside of that tab. Any suggestions?

Comment: As the error suggests, tabbar content must be `ons-page`, which in React is `<Ons.Page>`. Wrap your `<Ons.Navigator>` inside a page and it works.

Comment: Oh my goodness, how could I possibly miss that... Thank you a bazillion!